# $C_0$-semi-group of a finite-state Markov chain

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains, semigroup-of-operators

I am studying semi-groups and infinitesimal generators from the book by A. Pazy, and I wish to understand the semigroup and infinitesimal generator associated with a finite-state continuous time Markov chain, say $X = \{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, with state space $\chi,\ |\chi| = k$.\

I have read in some lecture [notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9JXBXeYBX6xzUDdjM58Ew7Lp-NenTV-/view) that the $C_0$-semigroup $T = \{T_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, acting on the space of bounded linear operators on V $(BL(V))$, where $V = L^{\infty}\left(\chi \to \mathbb{R}\right)$, given by
$T(t)f(x) = E[f(X_t)\vert X_0 = x]$
is the semigroup for the Markov process $X$. In the accompanying proof, its infinitesimal generator of $X$ is found to be its own transition rate matrix / Q-matrix $\Lambda = \left(\lambda_{ij}\right)_{k \times k}$.\

I do not understand this - how is $\Lambda$ an operator on $V$? By definition, $\Lambda$ can operate only on vectors with dimension $k \times 1$, but elements of $V$ are scalars. Is $V$ actually supposed to contain all possible outputs of $ L^{\infty}\left(\chi \to \mathbb{R}\right)$, because then the dimensions match.

Comment: Let's say $\chi=\{1,\dots,k\}$ for simplicity. The $V$ contains all bounded measurable functions from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Of course, when $\chi$ is endowed with the power set as $\sigma$-algebra, measurability is not an additional assumption, and neither is boundedness. So $V$ is the set of all functions from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which is one possible definition of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: @MaoWao , thank you so much for your reply! Could you please elaborate by what you meant in your last sentence? I am having trouble visualizing the matching dimensions for $\Lambda$ and elements of $V$.

Comment: If you want, there is an isomorphism $V\to \mathbb{R}^k$ given by $f\mapsto (f(1),\dots,f(k))$ with inverse $(x_k)\mapsto f$ with $f(k)=x_k$. But this is really only a matter of writing things differently (and a formal definition of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is $\{f\colon \{1,\dots,k\}\to\mathbb{R}\}$).

Comment: @MaoWao thank you! This has been very helpful!

Comment: @MaoWao I also realise I do not understand how the semigroup and the infinitesimal generator connect to the finite-state Markov chain. Could you please provide a hint or a reference?

Comment: The computations are on the slides. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @MaoWao maybe it is silly, but why does the Markov chain have that semigroup representation? The slides just takes some family of operators, shows that it is a semigroup and computes its infinitesimal generator. How can I verify that they are related to / derived from $X$?

Comment: The family of operators is related to the Markov chain by the very definition in the slides (also present in your question).